# How to apply path in clipboard in Total Commander

Tags: path, clipboard, total-commander

I know there is a feature in Total Commander that copies actual path into clipboard. I need the opposite, which uses the **path in my clipboard** and **navigates to it**, so that I don't have to click on the address bar and paste it in there. 
I can't find such a command. Is it possible to create one somehow?

Comment: I don't think there is a command for this. But if you want to avoid clicking the address bar, you could bind `cm_EditPath` command to something like CTRL+G. You would then hit CTRL+G, which would focus the address bar, hit CTRL+V, which would paste the path and hit Enter to go to specified directory. It's not exactly what you want, but it might be quicker as you don't have to use a mouse.

Comment: @ViktorPless can you share the shortcut for opposite? I'm doing **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** followed by **Shift + Right** and **Ctrl + x**

Comment: I can type "cd " then hit Ctrl-V  and Enter and it changes the directory.

Answer (score 1):

What am I using is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> (which moves you to command line) and then type cd *path* (where path is in your clipboard - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).